# Unity Terrain Glossy with White Patches

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain, world-map, unity3d-terrain

I am new to Unity and I am having difficulties applying the terrain tools. How can I fix glossy terrain with white spots within 2021.3.5f1 Unity? I'm unsure why this is happening to all of my terrain layers.

The textures are from the Unity Terrain Tools asset

[image]
[image]

I even deleted the terrain I created above and created a new 3D object > Terrain (without any adjustments). I painted the new terrain with the Unity asset textures used in the world above.
Then I started raising the terrain to create mountains, but this caused it to create white spots on the scene. See the image below:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? What would be the correct way of importing assets or textures within assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert Rendering Pipeline in Unity 2021.3.5f1's verison